# How to calculate the Time complexity of my C function

Tags: c, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I wrote a function to calculate the number of ones in the binary of a decimal number. If the input is 3 then its binary will be 0011 and it should print the output as two. Because there are two 1 in the binary number.How can i calculates time complexity of this function?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
    void numberof_1(int n)
      {
        int i,count=0;
        if ((n & 1)== 1)
        count=count+1;
        printf("%d",count);
        for(i=0;i<32;i++)
         {
           n= n >> 1;
           if ((n & 1)==1)
            {
              count=count+1;
            }
          }
    printf("\nthe number of ones =%d\n",count);

      }
    numberof_1(10);
    }
```

Comment: Is the number of loop iterations dependent on anything in the input? If not, the complexity is O(1).

Comment: The algorithm is not dependent on the size of the input (since you are always processing a single 32-bit integer); the time-complexity is therefore O(1).

Comment: Side-note: What you're trying to do is called a "population count" or "popcnt" for short. Some architectures have a dedicated instruction to do this, for others, you might want to look at the portable C solutions for this found on [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't think he's "trying to do this". His exercise is in complexity theory, not bit twiddling.

Comment: what if the loop iteration dependent on input?

Comment: @GovindParmar: It could be described in more general terms for arbitrary width values (even if that's not a concern for the limitations of C specifically), which would make this algorithm linear in terms of bit count, `O(n)`. There are solutions that are closer to `O(log n)` in bit count, but they ignore practical realities (on a real CPU, multiplication is more expensive for larger values, even if you count a multiply as one "operation" theoretically).

Comment: I know the basic coding of c and python. But know nothing about complexity.. :( @shadowRanger

Comment: Is there any method to reduce the complexity? @ShadowRanger

Comment: @project_ananthu: See my earlier link. It's not really about theoretical, big-O complexity in the real world for fixed width values, as Govind says, but there are algorithms that are much more efficient on constant factor and practical CPUs; that is, your solution involves lots of unpredictable branching (losing instruction pipeline), 32 loops and a hundred operations or so, but there are branchless solutions that don't loop at all and use only a dozen or so operations to get the same result; both are `O(1)` for a C `int` (the work is constant), but it's a bigger constant for bad solutions.

Comment: thank u very much....  is there any logic that not need to go through all the 32 bits so that i can avoid going through the unnecessary 0's @ShadowRanger

Comment: @project_ananthu: That's exactly what "Brian Kernighan's way" at my link covers. The loop executes once per bit set. But on average that means 16 loops (>50 "operations"); "Counting bits set, in parallel" doesn't loop at all, and uses exactly 12 "operations" no matter how many bits are set (or not). Read the various "Counting bits set" solutions, and you'll learn more than I can express in the comments here. I will not respond to further questions that are easily answered by clicking the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When speaking from purely algorithmic point of view, the time complexity of `numberof_1()` is `O(log(n))` (where `n` is the input number).

The number is represented in binary base, and thus have `log_2(n)` bits representing it. Your algorithm is iterating all these bits.

However, note that to really achieve that `O(logn)` time complexity, you should add a conditional `break` when `n==0` (to avoid redundant iterations on a number which is already 0).

---

From technical point of view,  integers are represented by constant number of bits, and if you refer to this size as constant indeed - the algorithm run time is `O(1)`, as the number of iterations is limited and there is a hard bound for the number of iterations needed.